# How do I parse an HttpExchange request after an ending slash?

Tags: java, http, request

I have a request as follows:

```
localhost:8000/location/:01
```

My code takes as input an HttpContext request.

```
func(HttpExchange r) {
   String area_path = r.getRequestURI(); // Equals string "/location/"
}
```

How do I parse an HttpExchange correctly so I can pull out the "01" from this path and store it as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

That (`localhost:8000/location/:01`) is not a valid URL or URI

A plain colon character is not legal in the path of a URL or URI.  If you want to put a colon in the path, it must be [percent-encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  Furthermore, if this was a URL, it would start with a protocol; e.g. `http:`.

Now ... it is unclear what the HTTP stack you are using will do with a syntactically incorrect URL / URI, but it could simply be ignoring the colon and the characters after it.

Your code looks a bit odd too.  You have tagged the question as `[java]`.  But the code looks like JavaScript rather than Java; i.e. `func` is a Javascript keyword.  But it also looks like you are using the (deprecated) `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange` Java class.  I don't know what to make of that ...

---

My advice:

1. Don't use a colon character in the URL path.
2. If you *must* do it, then [percent-encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the colon it.
3. If you *cannot* encode it properly, then you may need to find and use a different framework for your HTTP request handling.  One that will accept and handle a *malformed* URL / URI in the way that you want.  (Good luck finding one!)

Unfortunately, the details in your question are too sketchy to give more detailed advice.

Comment: Thank you Stephen! That was my first question on stack, so apologies if it was too vague.